# How to change toolbar skin in Media Player Classic - Home Cinema?

Tags: windows-8, themes, media-player-classic, appearance, skin

I am following [this link](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mpc-hc/wiki/Toolbar_images) to change toolbar skin of [Media Player Classic - Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) but it is not using the new skin. I'm using Windows 8 Pro N and [Media Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30685) is installed.

**More Information:**
MPC-HC version: 1.6.4.6052

Comment: Have you fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow from Windows Media Player:

1. Go to the desired website you have mentioned
2. Pick the toolbar that you like
3. Click "Download"
4. Extract the file
5. Get the *.bmp file that was extracted and copy it to the folder
   `C:\Program Files\MPC-HC` (or whatever the installation folder is).

There's [a YouTube video: How to change Media Player Classic Toolbar
(Play,Pause,Stop Button)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arQkZFOSnKI) that explains this process.

Comment: There is no such option. Are confusing windows media player classic with windows media player ?

Comment: just wait let me check..

Comment: Have you logged in as an Administrator?

Comment: Yes. http://i.imgur.com/HkjkN.png

Comment: Check my Current post...

Comment: hey did u check?

Comment: I had followed same video. There is toolbar.bmp in MPC folder but still not working.

Comment: Open up an account @ http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mpc-hc/,Create a ticket with your Screenshot they will reply back if there is a bug and all the details

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6324/discussion-between-serious-and-sant14)

Comment: That worked for me in the past in Windows 7. The question is about Windows 8. I can say that after installing MPC-HC 1.7.9 in Windows 10, the installation folder is C:\Program Files\MPC-HC, but there is no toolbar file there and copying a custom one there doesn't change anything. Or is it because of a MPC update change? -

Comment: - Have you tested your answer in Windows 8 and above?

Answer (score 0):

#### Process

1. Go to a website that provides MPC Toolbar Images, such as [this one](https://trac.mpc-hc.org/wiki/Toolbar_images)
2. Download the toolbar/image. If it's zipped, extract it.
3. Move the image file to the base installation folder (where the `.exe` is).

#### Explanation

Media Player Classic (MPC) themes are stored as a single `.png`, `.bmp` or `.svg`, which is loaded from the MPC installation base folder.

MPC is usually installed somewhere similar to either:

- `C:\Program Files\MPC-HC` or
- `C:\Program Files\Combined Community Codec Pack\MPC` (if it was bundled with CCCP).

There's also a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arQkZFOSnKI) that explains this process.